# Correct method to acquire the spatial coordinate system with HoloLens 2

Tags: c#, transform, hololens

So i am trying to wrap my head around the transformation from a frame taken via the MediaFrameReference class. The thing i got is an image with an associated spatial coordinate system and the intrinsic camera parameters.
To calculate the real world coordinate (X, Y, Z) of a pixel in the image (U, V) i thought it will be sufficient to access the 4x4Matrix which represents the transformation matrix from the RGB-camera to the world.

To do this i found the TryGetTransformTo(SpatialCoordinateSystem target) method. If i understand the documentation correctly i have the image coordinate system attached to the image so i would call

`image.CoordinateSystem.TryGetTransformTo(worldCoordinateSystem)`

- But i just can't find the proper way to do get hold of the `worldCoordinateSystem`.
  Apparently there was a part in the [locatable camera](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/locatable-camera) documentation which got erased.
- I checked the example from Microsoft ([HolographicFaceTracking](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HolographicFaceTracking)), but i am horribly bad at interpreting c++ code. So this is not quite useful to me.
- At [Sketchy Experiments with HoloLens](https://mtaulty.com/2018/06/19/sketchy-experiments-with-hololens-facial-tracking-research-mode-rgb-streams-depth-streams/) the programmer used
  `var unityWorldCoordinateSystem = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(WorldManager.GetNativeISpatialCoordinateSystemPtr()) as SpatialCoordinateSystem;`, but it is declared as obsolete.
  Using this information and extremly good google-search-skills i found this [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1724250/what-is-the-alternative-to-unityenginexrwsaworldma.html).
  With a similar question which got never answered.

The question i have is, what is the most efficient method to acquire the spatial coordinate system i need.
I am using Unity 2018.4.22f1 and Visual Studio 2019.

Any help is very much appreciated. Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommend using `PhotoCapture` class to capture the picture, the TryGetCameraToWorldMatrix method of PhotoCaptureFrame will make it easy to acquire the Matrix4x4  to be populated by the Camera to world Matrix at the time the photo was captured. You can refer to this link to learn more about how to use it: [UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture.html)

Follow the guides, when you call the async method [TakePhotoAsync(onCapturedPhotoToMemoryCallback)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture.TakePhotoAsync.html), you need to pass in a function as a parameter, it will be invoked once the photo has been stored to memory. And in this function, you will get a PhotoCaputrerFrame instance as a parameter. Finally, invoke [PhotoCaptureFrame.TryGetCameraToWorldMatrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.WebCam.PhotoCaptureFrame.TryGetCameraToWorldMatrix.html) on this parameter to acquire a matrix to be populated by the Camera to world Matrix at the time the photo was captured.

Besides, for an early version of the MR documentation, it has demonstrated how to find or draw at a specific 3d location on a camera image with shader code, you can find it on GitHub commit history: [mixed-reality-docs/locatable-camera.md.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mixed-reality/commit/a0b2c53dc295db0332832ba00b60bd7a4962e3d9#diff-39e0f47742e9a5498952f06fa42c0099R91)

Comment: Many thanks for the information. I will continue to look at the last link, but I think that unfortunately it is not applicable for me.
I would like to continue to use the MediaFrameReference class, as I would like to work with time-correlated depth data later.
Is there a possibility to get the 4x4Matrix with this class?

Comment: Just read about the [stationary frame of reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/coordinate-systems#stationary-frame-of-reference) part where they say that at app start there is a stationary frame of reference. How would i access this one? And would it be good programming to use this with its attached coordinate system? Or should i work with the SpatialLocator class and generate my own reference-frame with the CreateStationaryFrameOfReferenceAtCurrentLocation() method?
Sorry i am really new in this field.

Comment: Yes, usually we use the Unity provided coordinate system when developing on Unity, you can refer this code to get it: `(SpatialCoordinateSystem)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(WorldManager.GetNativeISpatialCoordinateSystemPtr())`. But, if you would not like to use the UnityEngine.XR.WSA API because it’s already marked as deprecated. `SpatialLocator` is an alternative for it, you can use `SpatialLocator.GetDefault().CreateStationaryFrameOfReferenceAtCurrentLocation().CoordinateSystem()` to create a coordinate system with the origin placed at the device's position as the app is launched.