# Unable to cast object of type 'SpatialCoordinateSystem' to type 'SpatialCoordinateSystem'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting, hololens

The code:

```cs
var coordinateSystem = PerceptionInterop.GetSceneCoordinateSystem(Pose.identity);
Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem unityCoordinateSystem = (Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem) coordinateSystem;
```

The output:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SpatialCoordinateSystem' to type 'SpatialCoordinateSystem'.
```

I'm working with a Hololens 2 and Unity and I tried to implement scene understanding. For this reason, I downloaded the [scene understanding example project](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples) provided by Microsoft themselves. They used Unity editor version 2020.3.12f1, whereas I tried to upgrade the project using Unity 2021.3.11f1. Almost all problems from upgrading are solved now (e.g. changing the `Api Compatibility Level` in Player Settings to get `System.Numerics` working), but one problem remains.

In the method `GetSceneToUnityTransformAsMatrix4x4`, they used a now deprecated package (UnityEngine.XR.WindowsMR.WindowsMREnvironment) to [get the Unity coordinate system](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples/blob/main/Assets/SceneUnderstanding/Core/Understanding/Scripts/SceneUnderstandingManager.cs#L1360). I needed to replace this line, so I found both [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73187357/how-to-access-the-hololens2-origin-spatialcoordinatesystem) and the answer's origin on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/10082#issuecomment-905865993). Apparently, all I had to do was to replace

```cs
SpatialCoordinateSystem unityCoordinateSystem = SpatialCoordinateSystem.FromNativePtr(UnityEngine.XR.WindowsMR.WindowsMREnvironment.OriginSpatialCoordinateSystem);
```

with

```
SpatialCoordinateSystem unityCoordinateSystem = PerceptionInterop.GetSceneCoordinateSystem(UnityEngine.Pose.identity) as SpatialCoordinateSystem;
```

and add `using Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR;` at the top of the file.

However, when I tried this, `unityCoordinateSystem` was always `null`. Just for the sake of it, I tried casting it using parentheses, and subsequently got the `InvalidCastException` described in the title. I'm new to C# and can't make any sense of it. Here are some more debug logs and their outputs:

```cs
var coordinateSystem = PerceptionInterop.GetSceneCoordinateSystem(Pose.identity);
Debug.Log("Coordinate system: " + coordinateSystem.ToString());
Debug.Log("Type of coordinate system: " + coordinateSystem.GetType().ToString());
Debug.Log("Coordinate system is of type Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem: " + (coordinateSystem is Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem));
Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem unityCoordinateSystem = (Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem) coordinateSystem;
```

```
Coordinate system: Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem
Type of coordinate system: Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem
Coordinate system is of type Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem: False
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SpatialCoordinateSystem' to type 'SpatialCoordinateSystem'.
```

I've read something about dlls of different versions, but I'm not sure how to check or if this is even correct. Maybe the `Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR` and `UnityEngine.XR` are conflicting...? Any pointers on how to solve this problem are appreciated!

Comment: instead of `coordinateSystem.ToString()` (which indeed basically equals using `coordinateSystem.GetType().ToString()` which again equals using `coordinateSystem.GetType().FullName`) try to use [`coordinateSystem.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname) .. this will pint out the unique actual type information including which assembly it belongs to -> maybe your geuss about different DLLs is correct

Comment: Can check the version of unity & known issues here for HoloLens.  For sure, 2021 had one that needs to be at least .14f1:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/known-issues#resolved-blocking-issues

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer to my question, but rather a workaround that did the job. I stumbled code from the MRTK scene understanding observer, which isn't quite the same as the scene understanding SDK, but still has similar code. Specifically, I've used lines [796-804](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/e140bf2527f790d2c810ec1ffdecb3ddab8c3b00/Assets/MRTK/Providers/Experimental/WindowsSceneUnderstanding/WindowsSceneUnderstandingObserver.cs#L796-L804) from the `WindowsSceneUnderstandingObserver` and modified them a little to fit the `SceneUnderstandingManager` code I'm working with. My code looks as follows:

```
private System.Numerics.Matrix4x4? GetSceneToUnityTransformAsMatrix4x4(SceneUnderstanding.Scene scene)
{
    System.Numerics.Matrix4x4? sceneToUnityTransform = System.Numerics.Matrix4x4.Identity;

    SpatialGraphNode node = SpatialGraphNode.FromStaticNodeId(scene.OriginSpatialGraphNodeId);
    if (RunOnDevice && node.TryLocate(FrameTime.OnUpdate, out Pose pose))
    {
        var result = Matrix4x4.TRS(pose.position, pose.rotation, Vector3.one).ToSystemNumerics();
        return ConvertRightHandedMatrix4x4ToLeftHanded(result);
    }

    if (RunOnDevice)
    {
    ...
```

Before this workaround, I also tried [their code](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/e140bf2527f790d2c810ec1ffdecb3ddab8c3b00/Assets/MRTK/Providers/Experimental/WindowsSceneUnderstanding/WindowsSceneUnderstandingObserver.cs#L810) to get the `worldOrigin` coordinate system:

```
SpatialCoordinateSystem worldOrigin = WindowsMixedReality.WindowsMixedRealityUtilities.SpatialCoordinateSystem;
```

Unfortunately, I had namespace problems once again. The original code expects an object of type `Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem`, but the above code returns type `Microsoft.Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem`, so just a `Microsoft` in front.

In the end, I didn't want to waste any more time than I already had, and since the workaround worked, I left it at that.